# spring boot read properties from yml file

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where properties have to be read from a yaml file.

code:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class ResourceProvider {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return env.getProperty("app.max.size");
    }
}
```

yaml file

```
app:
  max:
    size: 10
```

When I try this it doesn't work. I get value for `app.max.size` as null. For `size` I get the value as 10.

When I use application.properties. I am able to get the desired result.
Am I doing anything incorrectly?

application.properties

```
 app.max.size=10
```

Comment: for yml file it also will be work. check your file. is it yml or yaml?

Comment: @PropertySource("classpath:application.yml") typo

Comment: @sajib, I have tried with both .yml and .yaml, still getting null.
If I try `app`, I get blank string as the result.

Comment: @dassum, what is the typo? if there would have been a typo, how can I get value for `size`?

Comment: Read the Spring Boot Documentation. It will automatically read `yaml` files given the correct convention.

Comment: It will be yml. Is yml file and properties file exists in same path?yml file works fine in my project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you'r using `application.yml` file, you don't need to manually load the file to the context as it's the default config file for `spring` application. You can simply use them in a `@Component` decorated class like below;

```
@Value("${app.max.size}")
private int size;
```

If you're laoding custom `YAML` file, then this is a huge problem in Spring yet. Using `@PropertySource` you can't load YAML files simply. It's possible, but little work required. First you need a custom property source factory. In your case, custom YAML property source factory.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Properties;

public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    /**
     * Create a {@link PropertySource} that wraps the given resource.
     *
     * @param name     the name of the property source
     * @param resource the resource (potentially encoded) to wrap
     * @return the new {@link PropertySource} (never {@code null})
     * @throws IOException if resource resolution failed
     */
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource)
            throws IOException {
        Properties properties = load(resource);
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(name != null ? name :
                Objects.requireNonNull(resource.getResource().getFilename(), "Some error message"),
                properties);
    }

    /**
     * Load properties from the YAML file.
     *
     * @param resource Instance of {@link EncodedResource}
     * @return instance of properties
     */
    private Properties load(EncodedResource resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();

            return factory.getObject();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            /*
             * Ignore resource not found.
             */
            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof FileNotFoundException) throw (FileNotFoundException) cause;
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

And, you need to tell `@PropertySource` annotation use this factory instead of default one whenever you use it like below;

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config-prop.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class) // Note the file name with the extension unlike a property file. Also, it's not the `application.yml` file.
public class ResourceProvider { 

    @Value("${app.max.size}")
    private int size;
}
```

You can use your properties shown in above code snippet's `size` variable.

Though. If you're using a YAML array declaration to get properties, that would be little peculiar even if you use this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I will have to use this. But was looking for something where I don't have to implement `PropertySourceFactory`

Comment: This is very helpful. thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Nice one. Works !

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation:

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation. So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

[Official spring boot documentation reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

Answer (score 1):

You can't load yaml files using `@ProperySource` annotation. One thing, I found out was you can use the property `spring.config.location` where you can define comma separated yaml files location. I have attached the snippet below:

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "public.config.app", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Slf4j
public class AppServiceConfiguration {

    private Map<String, Object> ios;
    
    private Map<String, Object> android;
    
    private Map<String, Object> buildNumberForIOS;
    
    private Map<String, Object> buildNumberForAndroid;
    
     @PostConstruct
     public void checkIfYamlIsLoaded() {
            log.debug("APP YAML configuration loaded successfully!");
     }
}
```

This is how i have defined this property in application.properties:

```
spring.config.location=src/main/resources/app-application.yaml, src/main/resources/web-application.yaml
```

Here is my sample yaml file:

```yaml
public:
  config:
    app:
      ios:
        enableMyContent: true
        warnUserOnMultipleShippingMethods: true
        enableShowScanToOrder: false
      android:
        enableMyContent: true
        warnUserOnMultipleShippingMethods: true
        enableShowScanToOrder: false
      buildNumberForIOS:
        '951': enableCurbsidePickup
      buildNumberForAndroid:
        '585': enableCurbsidePickup
        '595': enableImpulseUpsellOnPDP|enableQuantityLimiter
```

Answer (score -2):

You can read the value by:

```
@Value("${app.max.size}")
private String size;  

public String getValue(String key) {
   return size;
}
```

Comment: I have multiple properties and don't want to define variables for this. New properties can be added and don't want to change this file.