# Spring Boot : YAML configuration not loaded to bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

role-permissions-mappings.yml

**Content:**

```
role-mapping-permissions: 
 rolePermissions: 
  - 
   role : 'role1'
   permissions: 
    -'role1'
    -'perm1'
    -'perm2'
  -     
   role: 'role2'
   permissions: 
    -'role2'
    -'perm1'
    -'perm2'
```

**Configuration class :**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="role-mapping-permissions")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Slf4j
public class RolePermissionMapping {
    
    private List<RoleDetails> rolePermissions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        if(!rolePermissions.isEmpty()){
            log.info("Role -Permission size {}",rolePermissions.size());
        }else{
            log.info("role-permission-mapping is not configured");
        }
    }
      
  
    public List<RoleDetails> getRolePermissions() {
        return rolePermissions;
    }

    public void setRolePermissions(List<RoleDetails> rolePermissions) {
        this.rolePermissions = rolePermissions;
    }
    
    public static class RoleDetails {
        private String role;
        private List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        public RoleDetails(String role,List<String> permissions){
            this.role= role;
            this.permissions = permissions;
        }
        public String getRole() {
            return role;
        }
        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }
        public List<String> getPermissions() {
            return permissions;
        }
        public void setPermissions(List<String> permissions) {
            this.permissions = permissions;
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Expected Output should be :**
Above code show output
**role-permission-mapping is not configured** instead of loading configuration and execute `log.info("Role -Permission size {}",rolePermissions.size());`

It need to use `@Value` annotation even after adding `@PropertySource` annotation. Is there any way to use without `@Value` annotation?

Comment: Where did you tell Spring to load file `role-permissions-mappings.yml`? *Hint:* [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) doesn't trigger loading of extra property files, you need a [different annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) for that.

Comment: [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) doesn't specify anything related to properties. Javadoc says: *Indicates that a class declares one or more `@Bean` methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime.*

Comment: this will help [spring boot read properties from yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944821/9050514)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got solution:

It need to implement YamlPropertySourceFactory

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource)
            throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());
        Properties properties = factory.getObject();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }

    
}
```

Config file seems changes with *YamlPropertySourceFactory to use for @PropertySource* and *empty constructor* implemented.

Update configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="role-mapping-permissions")
@PropertySource(value="classpath:role-permissions-mapping.yml",factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Slf4j
public class RolePermissionMapping {
    
    private List<RoleDetails> rolePermissions = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String,List<String>> rolePermissionMap;
   
    /*Empty constructor*/
    public RolePermissionMapping() {
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        if(!rolePermissions.isEmpty()){
            rolePermissionMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            rolePermissions.stream().forEach(rolePermissions->{
                rolePermissionMap.put(rolePermissions.getRole(), rolePermissions.getPermissions());
            });
        }else{
            log.debug("role-permission-mapping is not configured");
        }
    }

    public List<String> getPermissions(String role) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(role) || !rolePermissionMap.entrySet().contains(role)){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Role Name '"+role+"' not found.");
        }
        return rolePermissionMap.get(role);
        
    }


    public List<RoleDetails> getRolePermissions() {
        return rolePermissions;
    }

    public void setRolePermissions(List<RoleDetails> rolePermissions) {
        this.rolePermissions = rolePermissions;
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class RoleDetails {
        private String role;
        private List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        /*Empty constructor*/
        public RoleDetails(){
            
        }
        
        public String getRole() {
            return role;
        }
        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }
        public List<String> getPermissions() {
            return permissions;
        }
        public void setPermissions(List<String> permissions) {
            this.permissions = permissions;
        }
        
    }
}
```