# Springboot @ConfigurationProperties Not Injecting

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, configuration

I am having trouble getting my property file (export-fields.yml) to inject to a map. I've created the properties file in the resources folder, linked to the property source, created a configuration for the property object, and generated getters and setters with lombok, but still not getting anything populated into the fields map (fields = null). Is there something I'm missing? Here is the code I have so far

FieldReplacerProperties.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "export")
@PropertySource("classpath:export-fields.yml")
public class FieldReplacerProperties {
    private Map<String, String> fields;

public List<String> columnsToFields(List<String> columns){
        columns.parallelStream().forEach(column -> fields.get(column));
        return columns;
    }
```

}

FieldReplacerConfiguration.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FieldReplacerProperties.class)
public class FieldReplacerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private FieldReplacerProperties fieldReplacerProperties;

    public List<String> columnsToFields(List<String> columns){
        return fieldReplacerProperties.columnsToFields(columns);
    }
}
```

export-fields.yml

```
export:
  fields:
    id: number
    name: programName
    type: contractType
    term: contractTerm
    ...
```

How I'm accessing it

```
@Autowired
private FieldReplacerConfiguration fieldReplacerConfiguration;
//replace columns with fields
fieldReplacerConfiguration.columnsToFields(columns);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring boot read properties from yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939406/spring-boot-read-properties-from-yml-file)

Comment: @SachithDickwella yes it does thank you. I needed a PropertySourceFactory for the yml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a PropertySourceFactory and this fixed the issue.

@PropertySource Change

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:export-fields.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

YML Factory

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

@Override
public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) {
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

Properties properties = factory.getObject();

return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring loads properties from application.properties (or yml). Try moving properties from export-fields.yml to application.yml

Comment: Have a lot going on in the application.yml so wanted to move this outside to make things easier to maintain. Managed to solve the issue with a PropertySourceFactory

Comment: Understood, another option to avoid implementing PropertySourceFactory and load custom yml is follow a convention like application-<your name>.yml.  Example application-fields-yml.