# Spring Bean Self autowiring via ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to directly populate the configuration object from the YAML file using @ConfigurationProperties. But when I checked the person's object, name and age got populated but the child is null. I am using the spring boot 2.7.4 version. Is this not supported by spring or any other way to handle such a situation?

```
@ConfigurationProperties("config")
@Component
public class PersonConfiguration {

    private Person person;

    //setter getters
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Person child;

//setter getters of all 3 
}

config:
  person:
    name: "my name"
    age: 40
    child:
      name: "child1"
      age: 14
```

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot - you most likely need `@Configuration` instead of `@Component`.

Comment: Followed the same article. Tried the @Configuration also but the same result(child is null).

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939406/spring-boot-read-properties-from-yml-file

Comment: This link is more on the side where we have yaml and properties file. I am using the yaml and am able to load the partial data. Issue is when i am trying to inject same class object to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need `PersonConfiguration`

This will work:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("config.person")
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Person child;
   
    //setter and getters
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @DirkDeyne. It worked for me. But is there any way we can achieve this with a Configuration file? The reason for that is there is a list of Models (Person in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your child definition in config file doesn´t represent the Person class structure, it is missing child attribute. Try this:
config:
person:
name: "my name"
age: 40
child:
name: "child1"
age: 14
child: null

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same result(child is null)